# Remove a folder I created in /system/lib

Tags: adb, mount, system, selinux

I have root access and am able to remount. I created a folder in `/system/lib/` named `rfsa`, but I don't know why I cannot see or open that folder.

When I type `ls`, it is there. But when I type `ls -l`, I get this error

```
lstat './rfsa' failed: I/O error.
```

The first time I get this error, I have to reboot and root and remount again. 
Also, if I try `rmdir /system/lib/rfsa/` (I created this folder myself), I get this error

```
rmdir: rfsa: Read-only file system
```

Any ideas what can I try?

---

Here it is before the `ls -l` command:

```
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
```

After `ls -l` and getting the error, it changes to:

```
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
```

---

I don't have busybox, but the first time I try `mount -w -o remount -t ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system`, nothing is changed. After I get the file I/O error, this time I get:

```
mount: Read-only file system
```

Here is the `cat /proc/mounts` output, before I try to access the bad folder:

```
rootfs / rootfs ro,seclabel 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=949072k,nr_inodes=237268,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=949072k,nr_inodes=237268,mode=750,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=949072k,nr_inodes=237268,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
adb /dev/usb-ffs/adb functionfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/persist /persist ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/dsp /dsp ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modem /firmware vfat ro,context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0337,dmask=0227,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/tctpersist /tctpersist ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/hdcp /persist/data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /storage tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=949072k,nr_inodes=237268,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/block/dm-0 /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/default/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/read/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/write/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
root@idol4:/ # cat /proc/mounts | grep system
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: what is the output of `mount | grep system` when it says `rmdir: rfsa: Read-only file system`?

Comment: How do you remount? please try `mount -o rw,remount,rw /system`.

Comment: Might have to do with the `seclabel`, see: [What does the 'seclabel' mount option do?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191183/what-does-the-seclabel-mount-option-do) Can you check what extended attributes are set (`xattrs` should do that)?

Comment: I have rw access at first, but once I try to access the folder I created and get the I/O error, with "mount -o rw,remount,rw /system" too, I get: "mount: Read-only file system".

Comment: In case you've note tried it yet, try seeking suggestions in this direction: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ls+input+output+error+linux

Answer (score 0):

If you have a busybox you can try

```
busybox mount /system -o rw,remount
```

or use system `mount` command:

```
mount -w -o remount -t ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system
```

Comment: There is no busbox. But The system mount does not change anything at first (cause I already have rw access). But once I try to access the folder I had created (rfsa), the access is changed to ro and typing the command above too, returns:  "mount: Read-only file system"

Comment: I think you have filesystem error, like @ott-- says. I would run recovery and try repair filesystem. When custom recovery boots, try `adb shell` from PC, mount /system partition and delete bad directory. Or try repair filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

It is a mount-option that the fs is remounted readonly if an error occurs.

But for you problem with the folder:

Could it be that the foldername contains special characters (that includes spaces or backspaces)? Check it with `ls -b *` or `ls -q *` if your `ls` supports it.

Comment: I did try, but these options are not supported for ls. Any other suggestions? I tried `adb reboot recovery` but the phone reboots in a screen that has a graphic showing volume up/down, but I can not do anything there.